# Dropdown year list in Laravel not displaying

Tags: php, laravel

I want to generate a dropdown list that displays years and so far, here's what I've done. I created a method in my controller below.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class RUMSModel extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $dateFields = [];
    protected $dropdownFields = [];

    public $module_dir = '';
    public $module = '';
    public $importFields = [];

    public static $months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    public function selectYear($name, $startYear, $endYear, $selected = null, $options = array())
    {
        $years = range($startYear, $endYear);
        $years = array_combine($years, $years); // [2013 => 2013]

        return $this->select($name, $years, $selected, $options);
    }
?>
```

Use it to display in a Blade template:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="validation-latest_estimate_year"><b>Latest Estimate Year:</b></label>
      <select id="validation-latest_estimate_year" class="form-control" name="latest_estimate_year">
      <option value="">-Select Year-</option>
         @foreach($model->selectYear('year') as $year)
           <option value="{{$year}}" {{$year == $model->latest_estimate_year ? 'selected': ''}}>{{$year}}</option>
         @endforeach
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, the dropdown list doesn't display the years. I'm trying to figure out why but I ran out of ideas. Any guidance from the experts would help.

Comment: Show us the full code, where is your `$model` come from? What is `$this->select`?

Comment: hello thanks for taking your time replying. here's the code and ive updated my post.

Comment: where is your controller codes?

Answer (score 2):

Hello guys thanks for taking your time to answer this post. I found a way to make it work but i dont know if its the most efficient way to do this.

here's what ive done to make it work:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="validation-latest_estimate_year"><b>Latest Estimate Year:</b></label>
       <select id="validation-latest_estimate_year" class="form-control"
        name="latest_estimate_year">
       <option value="">{{$model->latest_estimate_year}}</option>
         @for ($year = date('Y') + 2; $year < date('Y') + 100; $year++)
            <option value="{{$year}}" {{$year == $model->latest_estimate_year ? 'selected': ''}}>{{$year}}</option>
         @endfor
       </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `selectYear()` from the [laravelcollective/html](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) package?

Install:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

View/Blade:

```
{!! Form::selectYear('year', 1900, 2019) !!}
```